# Simple boolean Promise in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm a bit confused as to how to create a simple promise in javascript to act as a flag for when a method has completed. For example:

```
const hasCompleted = Promise(false); // obviously not the way to create it
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = data;

img.onload = function(){
  hasCompleted = Promise.resolve(true);
};

hasCompleted.then(function(){
  // continue...
);
```

I realise I could just put everything inside the `onload` callback, but for various reasons (other dependences, etc) this isn't an option. Ergo, I believe Promise is the way to go. The guides I've looked at seem to be making this more complicated than it needs to be though. What is the *simplest* way to use a promise in the way I've demonstrated? Thanks.

Comment: When you create a `Promise` you use the `new` keyword and you pass the `executor` function of the `Promise`. Here is a documentation about Promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstood the problems that Promises came to resolve. I understand that you expect that when the promise is "true" (gonna explain below) the function pass to "then" will execute, but is not the way Promises work.

The Promise has two states, "resolve" and "reject", so if it's "resolve", meaning that the asynchronous value you're waiting is available already, the function passed to "then" will be executed, but if it's "reject", meaning that something wrong happen and the value you're waiting will not became available, the first "catch" in the chain wold be called.

I say "chain" because you can use as many "then"s and "catch"s as you like.

That said, I believe you don't need a Promise here, just a simple flag or a some kind of callback inside your `onload`.

### Creating a Promise

You can create a promise with two ways, the first one is just, from the documentation:

```
new Promise(/* executor */ function(resolve, reject) { ... });
```

Where the function as parameter receives two functions, one for you call when the async value is ready to use - the `resolve` - and one for you tell the chain that something wrong happen - the `reject`.

Another way of create a promise with the state set already is with `Promise.reject()` and `Promise.resolve()`.

### Waiting for async value without a Promise

A common pattern for waiting for something to load, like a DOM element, is with a `setInterval` and a `if` statement. Not saying is a good pattern... but here it is:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (/* what you want is available? */) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    /* use your value */
}, 500)
```

Comment: If a DOM element provides a load event, why would you use an interval instead?

Comment: I wouldn't not =). Actually I've tried to introduce the pattern, didn't said that was the case. Just thought that if he was searching for promises, would be useful know this trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need a promise there.

You can either directly call the other function or just set a variable to true.

Does this answer your question?

If not, please tell me more specific what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
const hasCompleted = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  img.src = data;
  img.onload = resolve;
  img.onerror = reject;
});
```

In order to create a promise that can be resolved at a later time, you use the `new Promise` constructor and do something with the `resolve` argument. Assigning a new promise over the old one won't do any good.